# Can anyone help identify this font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Can anyone help identify this font? 
Cover of Esquire Singapore magazine in 2014, I'm trying to find the font used for the name George.

Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: It's not a font - it's handwriting.  Not everything is a font!

Answer (score 2):

It's clearly not a font, to be a typographic font the two lowercase "e" characters should be the same or at list not so different from each other. You can find something similar searching on Google "brush font" or "handwritten brush font".

Seven differences why the *e* character does not belong to the same typographic family as alternate glyph:

[image: stroke1] 
[image: stroke2]
[image: stroke3]
[image: stroke4]
[image: stroke5]
[image: stroke6]
[image: height]

Too many differences to belong to the same design.

Comment: Not entirely true: the "e" can be different if a font has alternate characters.

Comment: But this is not true, it is possible to prepaere fonts with alternate glyphs that substitute based on how many characters preceeded them so that a font would give a illusion of variation

Comment: That's why i wrote – at list not so different from each other–. The two "e" looks like from a different alphabet design. The beginning of the path at the left, the internal contour, the axis of the ellipse, the inclination of the character... a big list.

Comment: well... "HapticScript has up to 14 variations for each glyph." You'll see in the "r" letter sample that they are completely different from each other, yet part of the same font https://weandthecolor.com/haptic-script-font-family-by-henning-hartmut-skibbe/51526 So nowadays character shape variation is not what defines if it's a font or not.

Comment: I see, but... checking the seven differences mentioned on the answer at list the stroke formal typology or structural axis for each character belongs to the same design. The typographic design of an alphabet is a process of **graphic systematization** of different elements, clearly visible in the typography you mention and non-existent in the example of the question.

Comment: Different is the case of the **trash design** from the 90's, where all the principles of the design were questioned and many fonts from that time were quite formally heterogeneous. But although never the differences, at least on my own experience seen and using font families, were as irregular as the examples of the answer.

Comment: Yes but the point is rather one could make a font like that if one wished. So characters being different is not a direct proof that it is a font. Anyay the smudge is a more better proof.